# How can I send or get a file through rest api

Tags: c#, restsharp

How can I move a file (for example: in pdf format) that is in a folder with me locally through an api call in a folder in a document management system?
This is a small cod section of the api call that takes over the task.

```
client = new RestClient("http://***.***.***.*");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("******", "******");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            request = new RestRequest("/*****/api/*****/*****/371 ", Method.POST);




            request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;

            request.AddParameter("Object", "{" +
                    "\"****\":\"*****\"," +
                    "\"name\":\"*******\"," +
                    "\"******\":\"2\"," +
                    "\"fields\":{" +
                    "\"*******\":{\"value\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "\"}" +
                    "}" +
                "}");
            request.AddFile("File", "C:/Users/********/Documents/****/*****/pdf.pdf");
            response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

I would have to obscure a few places with stars
Thank You

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The files cannot be moved from a local folder to a folder  in a document management system

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the response? What is the response status code?

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "The file" C: /Users/******/Documents/*****/*****/pdf.pdf "could not be found."

Comment: OK, that has nothing to do with the api call. Where is this code running? A server will not be able to reach into your c: drive, it will try to look in its own c: drive.

Comment: ok then you have to look for the folder file outside of the server, something like upload? then request.addfile is a wrong command.     the code runs locally in visual studio